# Get value of a textbox from a click button event

Tags: jquery

I have a input box and a button side by side. I have created a clic event for the button to get the value of the button

```
<input type="text" id="amount" value="" name="amounts" />

 <button class="breakbtn" id="btn">Button</button>
```

This is the event code

```
'click .breakbtn': function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
alert(amount);
```

`alert(amount);` turns out empty. Why is this the case?.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted all of your code so it's impossible to say for sure.  What I can say is that what you've posted would work if the syntax were cleaned up.

However, I'm guessing by your indentation that where you declare `var amount` and where you have `alert(amount)` are not in the same scope.

Move `var amount` to the top of your script (or at least outside of the function which handles the event) and all will be well.

Comment: @LeQs ... then it's not all your code.  Read my answer... where you close that function matters.

Comment: There is more to this than meets the eye,and its not the missing code which i assure you i have not left out.

Comment: @LeQs Then, make a small reproducible example.  Something that actually parses and runs but reproduces your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need read the [Api documentation of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) to see the syntax and functions.
Done, use this.

```js
$('.breakbtn').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
alert(amount);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="amount" value="" name="amounts" />

 <button class="breakbtn" id="btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    alert(amount);
});
```

Try the above code..